# What is preventing this div from inheriting styling?

Tags: html, css

Can someone please tell me why the `#controls` div cannot be styled and the items inside aren't inheriting styles from the `#wrap` div?  I cant figure it out and it's driving me crazy.

```html
<body>
 <div id="wrap">
  <div id="slider1">
   <ul id="slider_items" class="slider">
                <li><div style="width:200px;height:300px;background:#2aa198;"> 1</div></li>
                <li><div style="width:250px;height:300px;background:#268bd2;"> 2</div></li>
                <li><div style="width:100px;height:300px;background:#6c71c4;"> 3</div></li>
                <li><div style="width:170px;height:300px;background:#d33682;"> 4</div></li>
                <li><div style="width:300px;height:300px;background:#dc322f;">5</div></li>
                <li><div style="width:200px;height:300px;background:#cb4b16;">6</div></li>
                <li><div style="width:1000px;height:300px;background:#b58900;">7</div></li>
                <li><div style="width:100px;height:300px;background:#859900;">8</div></li>
   </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="controls" class="controls">
                <a href="#" class="prev-slide"></a>
                <a href="#" class="next-slide"></a>
   </div>
 </div>
 <script src="lemmon-slider.js"></script>
 <script>
 window.onload = function(){

  // slider 1
  $( '#slider1' ).lemmonSlider({
   infinite: true
  });
 }
 </script>
    
 <style type="text/css">
 #wrap { width:80%; margin:20px; background:#ffc; }
 #slider1 { overflow:hidden; position:relative; width:100%; height:300px !important; }
 #slider_items li { text-align:center; line-height:160px; font-size:25px;  float:left; list-style:none; margin:0 5px 0 0; }
 .prev-slide {position:absolute; display:block; float:left; height:300px; width:100px; background: #C0C0C0; cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;}
 .next-slide {position:absolute; display:block; float:left; right:0; height:300px; width:100px; background: #C0C0C0; cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;}
 #controls {background-color:#F8E5C9; top:100px;}
 </style>

</body>
```

Comment: what styles are you trying to inherit from `#wrap`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the property you want to inherit from its parent and do {property: inherit}, in this case, I'm guessing you want to do:

```
{
  width: inherit;
  margin:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More than asking what, it is easier if you open in Internet Explorer Developer Tools and it will tell you what inherited value overwrites your style.

I know IE is not nice, but the dev tools are amazing. Just open IE, go to your page and press F12.

With Chrome you can do the same or Firefox.

If you don't want inheritance, you can use **!important** as keyword in your css.